# Unable to plot marker on the map using json

Tags: android, json, google-maps

The marker is not showing on the map, json data is totally fine and i can see that while debugging.but marker is not showing on the map

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback  {
public GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


public void onMapSearch (View view) throws IOException {

    //hide button when button is pressed
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

    //preview the entered address as an Tost in bar
    EditText locationSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String location = locationSearch.getText().toString();

    //this will animate camera and zoom 12.0f
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12.0f));



    //further address search codes
    List<Address> addressList = null;

    //if nothing will be entered in the edit-text will not show a toast rather than crashing of thekha app
    if (locationSearch.getText().toString().equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Bitch please enter A Value",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {

        //process of exception handling and finding location
        if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            //if address is greater than one then these processes will happen

            if(addressList.size()>0) {
                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title(location + " is Here- ")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                Toast.makeText(this, location+" is here, Zoom In or Zoom Out to make your Thekha Visible ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show(); //popup type to show entered data
            }
            else {
                //process where entered entry will not gonna find , this will gonna a toast to show popup

                Toast.makeText(this,"Entered Address Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

    }
}


private class RetriveMarkerTask extends AsyncTask<StringBuilder,Void,StringBuilder> {
    private Context context;
    private String jsonData;

    public RetriveMarkerTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected StringBuilder doInBackground(StringBuilder... stringBuilders) {
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            //connect to the web service
            URL url = new URL("http://www.loofre.com/api-for-webservice/?debug=true&action=getLocations");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
            //This will read the json data into string builder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                json.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
            this.jsonData = new String(buff);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
            return json;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
        super.onPostExecute(stringBuilder);
        try {
            ((MapsActivity)context).createMarkerFromJson(this.jsonData);
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



void createMarkerFromJson (String json) throws JSONException {
    // de-derialize the json string into an array of objects


        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int i =0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            //create marker of each place in the json data
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String placeName = jsonObject.getString("name");
            String placeAddress = jsonObject.getString("address");
            double latitude = jsonObject.getJSONArray("latlang").getDouble(0);
            double longitude = jsonObject.getJSONArray("latlang").getDouble(1);
            LatLng loc = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 13));
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(placeName)
                    .snippet(placeAddress)
                    .position(loc)
            );
        }

    }

//OnReady map starts here when we can enter or add Marker to the map
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
   mMap = googleMap;

    try {
        RetriveMarkerTask markerTask = new RetriveMarkerTask(this);
        markerTask.execute();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Can not fetch data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
            (this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //  int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    //tool bar and other tool related on map uiSettings
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

}
```

}

Comment: are you getting the Lat and Lng individually or a single LatLng. Means are you getting Lat = "x" and Lng = "y" or LatLng = "xy"

Comment: getting .... individually

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the context to your task and then casting the context back to call a function, why not just pass the mMap in your constructor and then move your createMarkerFromJson function inside of your AsyncTask class. If the Json data coming back is correct, this will help us verify that your marker is being added to the correct thing. Does your call to moveCamera occur?

Comment: remove the call to the super class onPostExecute, it doesn't need to be there and it's probably crashing the onPostExecute before it even does your marker creation

Comment: removed super still not working .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486392/unable-to-plot-marker-using-json-and-onpostexecute-no-response

please visit this link i have updated few codes too ...help me sir